# How to cat <<'EOF' arbitrary text data from clipboard

Tags: linux, bash, clipboard, tty

I want to paste some text into a terminal and save it to a file without using an editor, but just 'cat'.
But too long lines or tabs in text make it impossible to do so with a simple command like "cat >test.txt" or "cat <<'EOF' >test.txt" ("here document").

In bash in "here document" mode if pasted text data contains tabs, they cause autocomplete.
If I start bash with '--noediting', on some systems the length of pasted line is limited to 256 chars, the rest of pasted text is discarded.
If instead I paste directly to cat's input (without <<'EOF'), the max line is also 256.

If I do:

```
stty raw; cat >test.txt; stty sane
```

, the line length is no longer limited, but there's no way to send EOF to cat's input.
If I enable eof char:

```
stty raw icanon eof '^d'; cat >test.txt; stty sane
```

long lines are lost.

Also, if I don't disable echo with:

```
stty -echo
```

, the combination of Solaris 10 and Putty cause large blocks of text ~1500chars to be lost, sometimes resulting an empty file.

The closest I got to what I want is to kill cat with timeout:

```
( sleep 15; pkill cat ) & stty raw -echo; cat >test.txt; stty sane; echo done
```

or to use bash --noediting with raw:

```
bash --noediting
stty raw -echo icrnl
cat <<'EOF' >test.txt; stty sane
```

Comment: Can you please say your question more clearly and what are you going to do?

Comment: Please don't downvote. If you don't understand the question, it means you're not a specialist. Your negative vote repels people who  could answer.

Comment: I don't downvote you can see my reputation, BUT please say your question clearly and edit your post, Thanks

Comment: I am still not sure what you are trying to do. I would guess you are trying to paste from your X clipboard into a file without opening an editor. Also I am not sure if you are looking for a scriptable or interactive solution. Such unclear things are probably the the reason for your downvotes. Googling  what I think is your question brought me to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749544/pipe-to-from-clipboard). Maybe `xclip -o > test.txt` does the trick for you.

Comment: @Tim I'm connecting to Solaris with Putty from a Windows session on a Citrix XenApp server, to which I'm connecting from Windows 7 with a XenApp client. I can't copy files, all I have is clipboard.

Comment: I could not see this from your question. Maybe you should clarify it. So if you want to transfer a file (or if this would help you), can't you just copy it first to your XenApp session (should be possible somehow) and from there using scp?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bash, you can disable tab-completion before you paste then reenable it afterwards by using the `bind` command:

```
bind '\C-i:self-insert'
# paste away
bind '\C-i:complete'
```

This is unwieldy, but it works.

When manually typing on the bash command-line you can enter a literal tab by first pressing CTRL-V then tab.  Obviously you can't do this when pasting and I was annoyed enough by this that I patched my favorite terminal program [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com) with a "Paste Special" command that sends literal tabs via a CTRL-V,tab sequence.

I only tonight wrote and submitted this patch, so if you want a version of iTerm2 that does this you'll have to compile your own from [my fork at GitHub](https://github.com/bdpdx/iTerm2) using Xcode.  Hopefully it will get merged into the main application, if it does I'll update this answer. EDIT: The changes I made are now in the main branch of iTerm2.  Use the Edit -> Paste with Literal Tabs command.

If you're using a different OS or terminal program sorry, I can't help with that.